# How to retain this jQuery event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I have an click even handler on a dom element.

```
jQcurrentOption.click(function () {
 //IMPLEMENTATION
});
```

When this element is cloned `.cloneNode(true)` it loses its event handler :(. I know that I can change the jQuery (note I am still using 1.4.4 hence `live` and not `bind`(1.7+))

```
jQcurrentOption.live("click",function(){
 //IMPLEMENTATION
});
```

However I was curious if there was a way to retain these handlers without defining them with `live` (or `bind`). Sometimes I don't have the benefit of using jQuery to apply `live`.

Comment: JQuery 1.7+'s `.on()` could be useful to you, but as you're using 1.4 you'll need another solution.

Comment: @Fabrício See my answer with regard to the need for "another solution" in 1.4.

Comment: @Tomalak Yes I'm aware of that. The `on` method replaces `delegate` in 1.7, the word "delegate" just skipped off my mind before commenting though. I wasn't fully aware of the clone hack, it may come in handy in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried jQuery's `clone()`?

```
var $clone = jQcurrentOption.clone(true);
```

It clones the event handlers if you pass `true` as an argument.

---

Apart from that, jQuery 1.4.4 supports `delegate()`, which is equivalent to 1.7's `on()`:

```
$("select").delegate("option.current", "click", function () {
 //IMPLEMENTATION
});
```

This way your individual elements don't need to copy event handlers.

---

Just to make a point: Even though `delegate()` is deprecated with as of 1.7, it really is the same thing as the more modern `on()`, the only difference being the argument order. Here's the current implementation (1.7.2):

```
delegate: function( selector, types, data, fn ) {
  return this.on( types, selector, data, fn );
}
```

Comment: This worked. I guess jQuery's clone is a little more powerful that the javascript one. Final solution I used: `var $y = $(x).clone(true);`

Comment: @TravisJ Yes. It also clones anything you put into `data()`. - In any case I would look into `delegate()` if I were you. Feels more like what you actually want.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) I will look into the delegate approach (does it support future elements or dynamic creation? it was hard to tell from the documentation which seemed to point to "yes").

Comment: @TravisJ Yes, it does. It *is* the same thing as `live()` or `on()`. You can bind event handlers to the parent container and *delegate* event handling to it - hence the function name. As a consequence, all dynamically created elements inside a container behave correctly right from the start. That's the whole point. (Also you don't need to use `clone(true)`, just using `clone()` is enough.)

Comment: The cloning is actually used as a hack and cannot be avoided (side note: the hack doesn't work without `true`). But thanks for the information about delegation, that sounds very promising - and the `.clone(true)` really came through :)

Comment: @TravisJ Just to be clear: jQuery does deep cloning by default. `true` does only mean *"also clone data and event handlers"*. So jQuery's `clone()` is equivalent to the DOM's `cloneNode(true)`. I'm pretty sure your "hack" would still work even when you use just use `clone()`.

Comment: Just to clarify: using `.clone()` will not preserve the event handlers in my scenario. Using `.cloneNode(true)` will not preserve the event handlers in my scenario. Using `.clone(true)` will preserve the event handlers.

Comment: @TravisJ Ah, right. I was talking about the `delegate()` scenario.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood that part. I don't have as verbose an example to test with `delegate` at the moment.

Comment: @TravisJ Yeah, just keep it in mind. It is a lot more handy than it looks, it's well worth the 10-minute-effort to learn it and switch from cloning event handlers to delegating them.